# differential equation with integral function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

Could you please help me with any information which would allow me to get an explicit solution for this equation?

It is an implicit solution to an optimization problem involving resource allocation in a game-theoretic setting. (I do not think this type of problems have been considered.)

$$y'(x)= 1-\frac{2\sqrt{2 y(x)}}{\int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{y(t)+y(x)}}} 
$$

Which class of integro-differential equations would it belong - so that I could search for a solution?

It is a specific parametric example for a more general problem
$$(2 y(x))^a f(x) = (1-y'(x)) \int_{x_{min}}^{x} a (y(t)+y(x))^{a-1} d F(t)$$
(given $a$ and distribution $F(x), f(x)=F'(x)$).

For $a=1$, the explicit solution is strikingly elegant:
$$y(x) = \int_{x_{min}}^x \left(\frac{F(t)}{F(x)}\right)^2 dt$$

Many thanks in advance

Comment: OK, seems to exist in English as well: [Integro-differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integro-differential_equation)

Comment: Looks weird. Where did this show up?

Comment: Thank you! Will look into the integro-differential equations.Though I am afraid mine might be a bit more complicated. (It comes as a first order condition to an unusual resource allocation problem with game-theoretic flavour.)

Comment: You will probably have to resort to some numeric method.

Comment: Many thanks for the leads!